# insserv issue - script doesnt start on boot

Tags: linux, oracle10g

I am trying to get oracle to start when my linux distro (opensuse 12.2) starts. The script works fine when run manually. But on restart nothing happens. When I run inserv I get these messages below, any idea why?

insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (3 5) of script `dbora' overwrites defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (empty) of script`dbora' overwrites defaults (2 3 4 5).

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my_oracle_database
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: my_oracle_database
# Description:       my_oracle_database
### END INIT INFO
export PATH=/oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin:$PATH
case "$1" in 
     start | startup | go | on)
        su - oracle -c "/oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/lsnrctl start"
        su - oracle -c /oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/dbstart /oracle10/product/10.2.0/  
        ;; 
     stop | shutdown | halt | off)
        su - oracle -c "/oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        su - oracle -c /oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/dbshut /oracle10/product/10.2.0/  
        ;; 
     *)
        ;; 
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably are these lines:

```
su - oracle -c /oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/dbstart /oracle10/product/10.2.0/
...
su - oracle -c /oracle10/product/10.2.0/bin/dbshut /oracle10/product/10.2.0/
```

`su` by default executes the command given using the `-c` option through `/bin/sh`, while passing all other positional arguments except the usernaem to the shell (as `$0`, `$1`, ...):

```
# su nobody -c 'echo prog:$0 args:$@' a b c d
prog:a args:b c d
```

In your script you're missing the quotes around the command, so you're executing `dbstart`/`dbshut` without parameters, while passing the path to the shell as `$0`.

Comment: I don't really know where and if oracle keeps logs, but you could try to add your own logging to the script (using the `logger` command to log to syslog, or just by redirecting output to a file with `>>`)